# Get proper term of person life using gmtime()

Tags: c++, ctime, difftime

I'm trying to calculate exact age of person using difference between now  and the date of birth. I'm getting difference in seconds, which, I suppose is correct value. Then i'd like to convert seconds into `struct tm`, using `gmtime()`. But it is giving me a `tm_year` on 70 bigger than it must be, and `tm_mday` on 1 bigger than must be. It seems to be clear about `tm_mday`- the range of it is from 1 to 31, I can just subtract 1 from, whereas `tm_year` is the years from 1900. OK, so why does `gmtime()` give me +70 years?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int main() {
int min,h,d,m,y;
struct tm bd = {0};
cout << "Enter birth date in the format: hh:min/dd.mm.yyyy"<<endl;
scanf("%d:%d/%d.%d.%d",&h,&min,&d,&m,&y);
bd.tm_year = y-1900;
bd.tm_mon = m-1;
bd.tm_mday = d;
bd.tm_hour = h;
bd.tm_min = min;

time_t now = time(NULL);
cout << "NOW: "<<now<<" BD: "<<mktime(&bd)<<endl;
time_t seconds = difftime(now,mktime(&bd));//(end,beginning)
cout <<"seconds elapsed: "<< seconds<<endl;
struct tm * age;
age = gmtime (&seconds);
cout << "year" << age->tm_year << endl;
cout << "mon" << age->tm_mon << endl;
cout << "mday" << age->tm_mday << endl;
cout << "hour" << age->tm_hour << endl;
cout << "min" << age->tm_min << endl;
cout << "sec" << age->tm_sec << endl;
```

}

output:

```
Enter birth date in the format: hh:min/dd.mm.yyyy
13:28/04.03.2021
NOW: 1614853702 BD: 1614853680
seconds elapsed: 22
year  70
mon   0
mday  1
hour  0
min   0
sec   22
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is translating "unix epoch time", which is seconds since 1970, to a date.

It is not converting seconds to an amount of days/months/years.  There is fundamentally no such conversion.  30 days can be less than or more than a month.  365 days can be a year, or 1 day less than a year.  24 times 60 times 60 seconds can be less than a day when a leap second happens.

Seconds after a point in time is a date.  But seconds does not uniquely map to a number of days/months/years.

Find the two points in time - dates - and compare/subtract components to do that.